# How to match duplicates and if match how to remove second one in list in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, portable-executable

I have the list of APIs,
Input  = [WriteConsoleA, WSAStartup, RegCloseKey, RegCloseKey, RegCloseKey, NtTerminateProces, RegCloseKey]

expected output = [WriteConsoleA, WSAStartup, RegCloseKey, NtTerminateProces, RegCloseKey]

Comment: As I see 'RegCloseKey' element has ocurred four times in a list.SO what do you mean by second one in a list?    I didn't get you expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Input = ["WriteConsoleA", "WSAStartup", "RegCloseKey", "RegCloseKey", "RegCloseKey", "NtTerminateProces", "RegCloseKey"]
Output = []
api=Input[0]
for index in range(1,len(Input)):
    if api!=Input[index]:
        Output.append(api)
        api=Input[index]
Output.append(api)
print(Output)
```

Try this hopefully it will work in your case.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply convert set(list) i.e. set(Input) to remove all the duplicates.